# Solve x in logarithm equation: $2\log_{10} (x-4) - \log_{10}4(x-1) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve $x$ for $2\log_{10} (x-4) - \log_{10}4(x-1) = 0$

I have the key with the answer 10 and have confirmed this is correct using Wolfram Alpha but which steps should I take to reach that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with original problem:
$$2 \log_{10} (x-4) - \log_{10}4(x-1) = 0$$

A rule of logarithm: $2 \log_{10} (x-4)=\log_{10}(x-4)^2$:

$$ \log_{10} (x-4)^2 - \log_{10} (4x-4)= 0$$

Another rule of logarithm: Express as the left side of the equation as a single product:

$$ \log_{10} \frac{(x-4)^2}{4x-4}= 0$$

Convert to exponential form:

$$ 10^{\log_{10} \frac{(x-4)^2}{4x-4}}= 10^0$$

or

$$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4x-4}=1$$

and when algebraically rearranging

$$x^2-8x+16=4x-4$$

or

$$x^2-12x+20=0$$

which is now a quadratic equation that you can solve.

Comment: I did what you (and @Timbuc) posted except I ended up with $x^2 -12x + 20$ as the quadric equation due to the minus @Semiclassical pointed out. However as only one of the two solutions to the equations is the answer in the key, $10$, how do I rule out the other solution $2$ from being the correct answer to the initial problem?

Comment: @user14124: Does $x=2$ make sense in the initial equation?

Comment: @user14124 Yeah it was $x^2-12x+20$; sorry, I'm an idiot. Also, you would rule out the $x=2$ because, if $x=2$, then one of the terms in the original expression $$2 \log_{10}(x-4)=2 \log_{10} (-2)$$ does not result in a real number.

Answer (score 5):

Use the properties of logarithms

$$k\log_ax=\log_a(x^k)$$

$$\log_ax-\log_ay=\log_a\frac xy$$

$$\log_ax=0\iff x=1$$